# iOS mainstay board how can I put 2 labels next to each other without overlapping

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have just started learning IOS swift development and I am creating a UITableView and have a prototype cell . I have 2 labels **City** and **State** . As shown here

[image: Prototype cell]

The fields obviously work correctly however what is happening is that the city and state labels are messing up and not appearing one after the other. Instead it shows one on top of the other like this
[image: How it displays in emulator]

How can I make it so that one label is not on top of the other ? like Chicago,IL . I been looking at other postings here but they mainly deal with html and not IOS any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Why do u even want to use 2 labels, Single Label will work. yourLabel.text = "Chicago" + "," + "IL"

Comment: Use auto layout. Also from your image it is not clear whether those label frames are actually overlapping or not

Comment: yourLabel.text = "Chicago" + "," + "IL", Replace "Chicago" & "IL: wth ur Variables

Comment: I am using 2 labels because the data is coming from 2 different Json fields, I will see how to group them together